# Error session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session error

Tags: php, session

I am running  my webserver and get the following error:

```
Error starting session: session_start():open(/var/lib/php5/sess_hienlq7a0i6im8tvfel989ji25, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Reinstalling php5 gave no results.

Comment: Create a file with just `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Look for what php.ini file is being loaded. Also check for the session save path. go into that php.ini file and set the session save path to something like a temp directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you want to close your question, here is my comment.

> Create a file with just `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Look for what php.ini
>   file is being loaded. Also check for the session save path. go into
>   that php.ini file and set the session save path to something like a
>   temp directory.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution:
Check to see which user is running the httpd/apache process.

```
$ ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

View the directory owner (the error will tell you the path)

```
$ ls -la /var/lib/session
```

Give ownership of the folder to the server user

```
$ sudo chown serveruser:serveruser /var/lib/session
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `chown www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions/` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
chmod 1733 /var/lib/php/session

chown root:root /var/lib/php/session
```

Reference: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115704